# Function And by PHP

Tags: php

```
public function getWithdraws(Request $request)
{
$data = Withdraw::where(['status' => 0])->latest('id')->paginate(10);
foreach ($data->items() as $key) {
$user = User::where(['id' => $key->user_id])->first();
$key->name = $user->name;
$key->balance = $user->balance;
$key->verified = $user->verified;
}
return response(['success' => $data]);
}
```

I have such a part of the code, this function outputs all the necessary records with status 0 in the database , how do I make sure that all records with statuses 0 and 4 are output ?

Thank you in advance for the answer

I tried to write comma-separated

Comment: This is not vanilla PHP but some third-party query builder implementation. You need to figure out which one (I see many static functions, so you may be using Laravel).

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, I arranged the code this way

```
$data = Withdraw::where(['status' => 0])->orWhere(['status' => 4])->latest('id')- 
>paginate(10);
```

Comment: You can also use a `whereIn`

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve records with statuses 0 and 4, you can modify the where clause in your query using the whereIn method. The whereIn method allows you to specify an array of values for a particular column, and it will retrieve records that have any of those specified values.

Here's how you can modify your function to fetch records with statuses 0 and 4:

```
public function getWithdraws(Request $request)
{
    $data = Withdraw::whereIn('status', [0, 4])->latest('id')->paginate(10);
    foreach ($data->items() as $key) {
        $user = User::where(['id' => $key->user_id])->first();
        $key->name = $user->name;
        $key->balance = $user->balance;
        $key->verified = $user->verified;
    }
    return response(['success' => $data]);
}
```

In the updated code, the whereIn method is used to retrieve records with statuses 0 and 4. The rest of the code remains the same, and the function will now return all the necessary records with statuses 0 and 4 from the database.